# How to find changeset associated to work item

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to get all changeset allsociated to work item i am able to get the workitem but could not get the changeset asssociated to workitem.

below is the code block which i am using to get the workitem

```
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
            tfsUri);
    WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tpc.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

    WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(
        string.Format("Select [Title] " +
        "From WorkItems " +
        "Where [ID] = '{0}' ", itemId));

    foreach (WorkItem workItem in queryResults)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(workItem.Title);
    }
```

Also tried below solution but its not working

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2005/09/21/472524.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation;

class ChangesetsFromWorkItems
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 2)
        {
            Console.Error.Write("Usage: ChangesetsFromWorkItems <server> <workitemid> [workitemid...]");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        TeamFoundationServer server = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(args[0]);
        WorkItemStore wiStore = (WorkItemStore)server.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

        int workItemId;
        for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(args[i], out workItemId))
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("ignoring unparseable argument {0}", args[i]);
                continue;
            }
            WorkItem workItem = wiStore.GetWorkItem(workItemId);
            List<string> associatedChangesets = new List<string>();
            foreach (Link link in workItem.Links)
            {
                ExternalLink extLink = link as ExternalLink;
                if (extLink != null)
                {
                    ArtifactId artifact = LinkingUtilities.DecodeUri(extLink.LinkedArtifactUri);
                    if (String.Equals(artifact.ArtifactType, "Changeset", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        associatedChangesets.Add(artifact.ToolSpecificId);
                    }
                }
            }
            string changesets = String.Join(", ", associatedChangesets.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("WorkItem {0} has associated changeset(s): {1}", workItemId, changesets);
        }
    }
}
```

below condition always returns false because extLink is null

```
if (extLink != null)
```

Comment: What TFS version are you using and are you talking to a TFVC or a Git repository?

Comment: Here you have full solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423721/finding-changesets-associated-with-the-work-item-or-having-specific-comment-tfs
It worked for me perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is not `ExternalLink` (e.g. none of the links can be cast to this type), then there is no external link associated to the work item.

Try looking at the `WorkItem.Links` collection in the debugger to see what kind of links are attached to it.

Comment: There was not a single changeset associated to the work item but i got it by applying recursive logic.